# Insert Into one duplicate update xx - Does it also update the INDEXes of the table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 30M+ rows, and each index update is expensive.
I sometimes have to update and/or add 5000+ rows in a single insert.
Sometimes all rows are new, sometimes some are new.

I cannot use update - since I don't know which is already in the table, so I use INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE for a single column.

This sometimes take a lot of time >5 sec.

Is there a better way to do it? maybe I did not explain myself clear enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you issuing 5000+ separate insert statements?  If so, lock the table while doing the inserts; it'll go a lot faster.

Comment: mmm. I put those 5000 rows into a single insert with separated values. I can try to lock the table and see the effect

Comment: If it's already in a single insert statement then locking the table is unlikely to make a difference.  What happens if you use `REPLACE` instead of `INSERT`?

Comment: locking did not change much, replacing will be much problematic.. will it not also rebuilding the indexes?

Comment: Pretty much have to rebuild the index (on some level) every time you add rows, whether you're adding them with a `REPLACE` or with an `INSERT`.  The point of locking the table was to prevent rebuilding the index again and again for each insert statement, but since you're only using one insert it wouldn't be an issue.  Sorry to say, but I doubt there's much else you can do.

Comment: quick clarification- if the insert into/on duplicate actually does not ** ADD ** anything, just updates - will it also update the index? or only for the new rows? if it updates the entire index - I might be able to update/add only the real changes ..

Comment: It shouldn't be updating the index unless there are new rows.

Answer (score 0):

I added BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT to perform the insert, and it enhanced performance by x4 to x10.